# How to avoid parent object methods while using reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I am assigning a child class object to a parent class reference. Using reflection i want to access the child class setter methods. I am able to get the child class setter methods but getting the setter method of parent class object too. I am explicitly checking the parent class setter method by hard coding the method names now. How can I avoid this?

```
public abstract class A {

String val;

public String getVal() {
    return val;
}

public void setVal(String val) {
    this.val = val;
}
}



public class B  extends A{

String valB;

public String getValB() {
    return valB;
}

public void setValB(String valB) {
    this.valB = valB;
}

}
```

---

```
A a  = new B();

        for (Method method : a.getClass().getMethods()){
             if (isSetter(method) && !(checkUnwantedMethods(method.getName()))) {
                 method.invoke(a, "someValue");
             }
         }

        public static boolean isSetter(Method method){
              if(!method.getName().startsWith("set")) return false;
              if(method.getParameterTypes().length != 1) return false;
              return true;
        }

        public boolean checkUnwantedMethods(String methodName){

            return (methodName.equals("setVal");

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `getDeclaredMethods()` and it will give you only the methods of the actual runtime object (i.e. considering dynamic binding) excluding inherited methods.

The problem that `getMethods()` retrieves inherited methods as well.